# How to build a XMLRPC client in Kotlin managing dependency with Gradle?

Tags: spring, gradle, kotlin, xml-rpc, kotlin-extension

Hi I'm working with Spring and Kotlin building an XMLRPC client but I don't find any resource about it... And I'm trying to install the apache Library to consume my xmlrpc client.
This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.51'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:${kotlinVersion}")
        // docker dependency
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE") 
        // APACHE XMLRPC DEPENDENCY
        classpath("org.apache.xmlrpc:3.1.3")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    } }
```

The build failed because it can't find the dependency.
*Does anyone have any idea how to install this dependency with Gradle Or another way how to face the XMLRPC with Kotlin and Gradle?*

Comment: dependencies are given as [`group:artifact:version`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html), your apache thing lacks the artifact, use `org.apache.xmlrpc:xmlrpc:3.1.3` (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlrpc/xmlrpc/3.1.3)

Comment: Thanks @zapl this resolve my problem.

Comment: In my case I was trying to import org.apache.xmlrpc:xmlrpc:3.1.3  but I needed org.apache.xmlrpc:xmlrpc-client:3.1.3 instead